# libgdx ImageButton scaleBy not work

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx. I want to scale image button on touchDown listener, but scaleBy  not work.

I  try with alpha or move methods and both method work fine, except scaleBy.

Here is me code:

```
    buttonSettings.addAction(Actions.scaleBy(5f, 5f, 0.5f)); //NOT WORKING
    buttonSettings.addAction(Actions.alpha(0.4f, 0.2f));//WORKING GOOD
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work, because of a performance optimization. You can use `setTransform(true)` on the button to disable that, which will in turn activate rotation and scaling on the button.

The full explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale).